How to create ARRAY<STRUCT<..>> parameters?
I'm using this crate to access BigQuery and I don't get how to create ARRAY<STRUCT<..>> parameters.
struct_values of QueryParameterValue is of type Option<Box>. How do I fix:
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Hello {
    pub bar: String,
    pub foo: String,
}

fn main() {
    let hello_array = vec![
        Hello {
            bar: "Bar1".to_string(),
            foo: "Foo1".to_string(),
        },
        Hello {
            bar: "Bar2".to_string(),
            foo: "Foo2".to_string(),
        },
    ];

    let query_parameter = QueryParameter {
        name: Some("hello_array_param".to_string()),
        parameter_type: QueryParameterType {
            parameter_type: "ARRAY".to_string(),
            array_type: Some(Box::new(QueryParameterType {
                parameter_type: "STRUCT".to_string(),
                struct_types: Some(vec![
                    QueryParameterStructType {
                        name: Some("bar".to_string()),
                        field_type: QueryParameterType {
                            parameter_type: "STRING".to_string(),
                            array_type: None,
                            struct_types: None,
                        },
                        description: None,
                    },
                    QueryParameterStructType {
                        name: Some("foo".to_string()),
                        field_type: QueryParameterType {
                            parameter_type: "STRING".to_string(),
                            array_type: None,
                            struct_types: None,
                        },
                        description: None,
                    },
                ]),
                array_type: None,
            })),
            struct_types: None,
        },
        parameter_value: QueryParameterValue {
            value: None,
            array_values: Some(hello_array.iter().map(|hello| QueryParameterValue {
                struct_values: Some(???), 
                value: None,
                array_values: None,
            }).collect()),
            struct_values: None,
        },
    };

    println!("QueryParameter: {:#?}", query_parameter);
}


QueryParameterValue::struct_values has a type of Option<Box<QueryParameterValue>> per the docs here.
i.e. it is a recursive structure.  This is why it's wrapped in a Box - it allows self-referential structures that would not otherwise be possible. The wrapped data is heap-allocated.
You should be able to populate struct_values using a pattern like this, nesting further if needed:
struct_values: Some(Box::new(QueryParameterValue {
    struct_values: Some(Box::new(QueryParameterValue {
        value: Some(hello.bar.clone()),
        array_values: None,
        struct_values: None,
    })),
    value: Some(hello.foo.clone()),
    array_values: None,
    struct_values: None,
})),

